# How to delete a recyclerrview item from a room database

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I have a program that I am currently working on. I need to make it so when I hit the "delete" button after typing the food name in, it deletes the recycler view item from the list and database. Here's a screen shot of what I mean:

[image: Image of app]

I have copy and pasted some of the main structures that I know I need to modify. I just do not know what exactly I need to do. These sections are commented out.

Here is the code in the MainActivity.kt:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var adapter: FoodListAdapter? = null
    private lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)

        adapter = FoodListAdapter(R.layout.food_row)
        food_recycler.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        food_recycler.adapter = adapter

        buttonAdd.setOnClickListener { viewModel.insertFood(Food(editFoodName.text.toString())) }

      //  buttonDelete.setOnClickListener { viewModel.insertFood(Food(editFoodName.text.toString())) }


        viewModel.allFoods?.observe(this, Observer { foods ->
            foods?.let  {
                adapter?.setFoodList(it)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

The code in FoodDao.kt:

```
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.room.Dao
import androidx.room.Insert
import androidx.room.Query

@Dao
interface FoodDao {
    @Insert
    fun insertFood(product: Food)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM foods")
    fun getAllFoods(): LiveData<List<Food>>

    @Query ("SELECT * FROM foods WHERE foodName = :name")
    fun findFood(name: String) : List<Food>
}
```

The code in MainViewModel.kt:

```
import android.app.Application
import androidx.lifecycle.AndroidViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel

class MainViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    private val repository: FoodRepository =
        FoodRepository(application)

    var allFoods:  LiveData<List<Food>>?

    init {
        allFoods = repository.allFoods
    }

    fun insertFood(food: Food) {
        repository.insertFood(food)
    }

//    fun deleteFood(food: Food) {
//        repository.deleteFood(food)
//    }


}
```

The code in FoodRepository.kt:

```
import android.app.Application
import android.os.AsyncTask
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData

class FoodRepository(application: Application) {
    val allFoods: LiveData<List<Food>>?

    private var foodDao: FoodDao?

    init {
        val db: FoodDatabase? =
            FoodDatabase.getDatabase(application)
        foodDao = db?.foodDao()
        allFoods = foodDao?.getAllFoods()
    }

    fun insertFood(newfood: Food) {
        val task = InsertAsyncTask(foodDao)
        task.execute(newfood)
    }

    private class InsertAsyncTask constructor(private val asyncTaskDao: FoodDao?) :
        AsyncTask<Food, Void, Void>() {

        override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Food): Void? {
            asyncTaskDao?.insertFood(params[0])
            return null
        }
    }

//    fun deleteFood(newfood: Food) {
//        val task = DeleteAsyncTask(foodDao)
//        task.execute(newfood)
//    }
//
//    private class DeleteAsyncTask constructor(private val asyncTaskDao: FoodDao?) :
//        AsyncTask<Food, Void, Void>() {
//
//        override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Food): Void? {
//            asyncTaskDao?.insertFood(params[0])
//            return null
//        }
//    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The thing here is that you need to update your recycler view with your new data:

```
recyclerView?.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Answer (score 1):

first you set the delete method setup.

```
@Delete
    fun deleteFood(product: Food);
```

your view model method is right and repository method is right.you call method in activity.

```
 buttonDelete.setOnClickListener { viewModel.deleteFood(Food(editFoodName.text.toString())) }
```

When you call the all foods then you need to update your recycler view with your new data.

```
viewModel.allFoods?.observe(this, Observer { foods ->
            foods?.let  {          
                adapter?.setFoodList(it)
              recyclerView?.notifyDataSetChanged() 


            }
        })
```

Comment: @KioraPulliam-Matthews    in Main Activity you already wrote viewModel.allFoods?.observe ... you need to just replace that code with my last section.

Comment: I get the error "Unresolved Reference: notifyDataSetChanged" when I try putting the code into the main activity

Comment: @KioraPulliam-Matthews you  remove this line  recyclerView?.notifyDataSetChanged()  from Main Activity. You only add notifyDataSetChanged()  on the end of the  FoodListAdapter in   setFoodList() method.